# Getting ID field of created model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm creating user accounts using code like this:

```
User.create({
  email: req.param('email'),
  password: req.param('password')
}).exec(function(err, user) {

    // I want to get the user ID in here...

});
```

and I want to grab the newly created user ID in the callback function. If I inspect the `user` parameter for the callback function to `exec()` it doesn't have an ID field, only the fields that I passed in (`email`, `password`) and timestamps (`createdAt`, `updatedAt`).

The only other way I can think of doing it is looking up the user again after creation by their email address, but that's a really bad way of going about it.

How can I get the ID of the newly created user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `exec`. You should be providing your callback as the 2nd argument to `create`

```
User.create({
  email: req.param('email'),
  password: req.param('password')
}, function(err, user) {
  console.log(user.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be ok. You should get the id from `user.id`

My test:

```
$ sails new app
$ cd app
$ sails generate api user
$ sails console

sails> User.create({email: 'email@example.com', password: '1234'}, function(err, user {console.log(user.id); }); // 1
```